# The from bs4 code is not working , though I have tried all the ways it show i need to convert the code

Tags: python

I have installed Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10 and then added the Beautiful Soup library. While importing it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 53
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (python setup.py install) or by running 2to3 (2to3 -w bs4).
```

Ant idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not installation help. A Python forum might be a better place for this questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty clear error message:

> You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3.

That is exactly what you're trying to do. Since you probably have Python 2 as well as Python 3 installed, try installing Beautiful Soup with

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

`pip3` is `pip` for Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have already installed bs4, but I could not import it, when I try to import it by coding the following 'from bs4 import beautifulsoup4' it shows the above error.

Comment: Have you installed it via `pip3`? Are you running your script with Python 3?

Comment: Also, there is only one version of python installed that is python 3.7.4  and beautifulsoup 4.7.5 is installed.

Comment: I have used pip3

Comment: I would try to completely uninstall Python, delete all folder associated (e.g. `C:\Python`), reboot and reinstall it. There is probably something seriously screwed up. You could also try `virtualenv` (https://virtualenv.pypa.io) before you do that.